# Problem with nvidia-settings, twinview and multiple workspaces

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces, twinview

Here's what happens:

If I have...

- ...only the laptop-screen activated
- ...window A on workspace 1
- ...window B on workspace 2

and open `nvidia-settings` and activate an external display (TwinView).

What happens then is that window A is moved to the left screen, and window B moved to the right screen **both on workspace 1**.

If I then deactivate the external display, all windows (including possible windows on workspace 3 and 4) ends up on workspace 1!

Is there a way to fix this? I just want each workspace to get *wider* I don't want windows to me moved around!

(Using Natty and Gnome. This wasn't the behavior in lucid.)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!